# Trapping keydown with basic JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keydown

I am fairly new to coding (Doing the foundation course on The Odin Project).
I am having some problems with the calculator project.

I want the calculator to be driven by both mouse & keyboard.
But when I press keys like "/", "." these are not trapped by Firefox or Chrome additionally Chrome is not trapping some more keys like "-" & "+".

```js
window.addEventListener("click", mouseClick);
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
```

The keyPress function simply calls the `element.click()` so that `mouseClick()` is emulated.

It seems if I press the above keys - the keys are not trapped by the "click" event handler.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

My System Details:
Firefox 93.0 / Chrome 94.0.4606.81 on Fedora 34 x64.

The two functions are below, as requested:
A small addition: I have uBlock Origin/ Bitwarden installed in Firefox (no addons on chrome), but I guess they should not interfere in anyway?

window.addEventListener("click", mouseClick);
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);

```
function keyPress(event){
    let keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if(keyCode === 13){
        keyCode = 61;
    }
    let btnPressed = document.querySelector(`button[data-key="${keyCode}"]`);
    if(!btnPressed){
        return;
    }
    console.log(btnPressed);
    btnPressed.click(); };

function mouseClick(event){
    if(!(event.target.tagName === "BUTTON")){
        return;
    }
    let currentButton = event.target.textContent;
    if(event.target.classList.contains("num-key")){        
        if(tmpNumArray.some(item => (item === ".")) && currentButton === "."){
            return;
        }
        tmpNumArray.push(currentButton);
        currNum = tmpNumArray.join("");
        refreshDisplay();
    }else{
        alert ("pressed operator");
    } };
```

Comment: Strange, works on my machine, tested with: document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{console.log(e)}); So if that is called it is in the part of your code that is calling "element". Can you put that part here?